# Determining the current carrying capability of a hollow cylinder

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, modeling, model

How can one analyze, to some approximation, the current-carrying capability of a hollow cylinder with a diameter of 3 inches and a length of 6 inches, made from 100 μm thick copper with a resistance of 30 mΩ, when current is applied to the top surface of the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: Calculate the power dissipation, surface area and temperature rise?

Comment: It could be all about the point (or otherwise) contact strategy/method.

Comment: That would depend how and which path the current will pass through the cylinder, where does it come out then? And current carrying capability, according to which specs, parameters, or limitations?

Comment: Current goes in one point and electrons (de)accumulate on it until the current source runs out of voltage compliance range, or it blows up.

Comment: Where, exactly, is ground on the cylinder?

Comment: There is no traditional ground, the discharge medium would be air to Earth ground through an arc.

Comment: At what frequency? The fact that the conductor is thin means that there is less drop-off in conductivity due to skin effect than would be true of a solid conductor.

Comment: The frequency range would be DC to 300Mhz.

Comment: How did you measure the 30 mΩ resistance of your set up?  Did you use a DC or AC current?  At 300 MHz you are going to have additional issues. For one the skin effect will restrict the current flow to the outer surface of the part. Also at that high a frequency the actual connection points and geometry of the part will affect the AC resistance/impedance.  For a reference on the skin effect see this calculator:  https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/skin-depth-calculator/

Comment: Well for simplicity let’s ignore skin effect. After someone helps with DC we can go evaluate with skin effect.

Answer (score -1):

If the axial resistance is 0.030 Ω, that tells you that the copper mass and six inch distance yields that much
resistance (assuming total circumference equally connected).

In the top-to-bottom conduction, distance is 3 inch times π/2 and the exact same mass of copper is carrying (assuming total length contact on top and bottom) the current.

So, diametrical resistance will be
$$0.030 \times { 3 \times \pi \over{ 6 \times 2} } = 0.0236 \ \Omega$$

It takes some more info, however, to know what 'current carrying capacity' is. What temperature rise does the insulation material, or local fire code, or cooling method allow?

Is the copper material or thickness really relevant info?